# "make instances real" behaviour has changed in Blender 2.9, how to get the same behaviour back as 2.8?

Tags: modeling, operator

"Make Instances Real" took a collection instance and made it into a collection

this collection would include collection instances if they existed, for example i might have a road instance with a road mesh, but lamppost instances

now it has change so the entire collection is flattened, it's much like a deep copy being chosen instead of a shallow one, so effectivly this means now it doesn't just create a group that's identicle to the orginal collection , it splits all the sub-collections up

to demonstrate this create:

CollectionA:
-add two cubes

CollectionB:
-CollectionA_INSTANCE (this is an group instance of GroupA)

then create a group instance of CollectionB, make it "make instances real", it will make the two cubes appear
however Blender 2.8 would have made an instance of CollectionA, not fully made sub-collections real also

How can i "make instances real" in Blender 2.9 like i used to in Blender 2.8?   (blender version 2.93.6 LTS)

edit: to put it another way
the old function replaced an instance with a duplcate of the collection in place

Comment: Well why don't you just duplicate the collection instance ? Maybe a screenshot or two might be more easily understandable ?

Comment: that doesn't duplicate in place, and my collections may even be located on a different scene

that's what i am forced to do but since they changed it, i'm just looking if there is a way of getting the old command back

Comment: not to mention scaling and stuff, with collection instances you can stretch something into place, rotate it, place it ... then you would "make instances real" replacing it with the collection

it would make the entire workflow pointless to simply duplicate the group and move it all into place one by one

Comment: Sorry still not sure exactly what the problem is. Could you add a screenshot of expected behaviour and current behaviour to see the difference ?

Comment: a screenshot doesn't show this... as the objects will look the same anyway. someone who has used this feature in 2.8 and 2.9 is the best person to answer this question.
.......
simply someone who has used the feature would be the right person to give an answer, or tell me how i have worded this wrong

Comment: I used Blender V2.8 and this functionality extensively and I don't remember it behaving differently. I just tested on 2.80 and using "Make instances Real" does not keep sub collection instances. Are you sure you didn't use another tool to do that ?

Comment: Maybe you mean to enable "Keep hierarchy" and "Parent" in the operator parameters using the panel in the lower left of the viewport ?

Comment: it was not them options, i was not aware of any addon i'd installed

unfortuantly i went from mac to windows during this process (laptop death), so i have now tested 2.8 here (windows), both version 0 and version 18 ... and find it the same as the new behaviour

Since i'm now unable to prove it sorry that leaves my question a bit impossible, thanks for your help but now i feel like i might have amnesia! Seriously i had a workflow centered around it, i'd place a road segment with lampposts, so it'd be road bits, with lamppost instances

Comment: i do appreciate you checking thanks.... i would like to try and leave the question open incase anyone has an idea if perhaps i was using an addon of linux/mac versions where different

Answer (score 1):

While searching for this topic I came across [this page](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/regarding-make-instances-real-not-respecting-hierarchy/14490/9) and it may give you more information. I think I'm looking for the same solution as you are but I'm sad to say, there likely isn't one at the moment. You have the options to Duplicate Collection or Instance to Scene, but the instanced collection will never keep its hierarchy properly once made real. Even objects emitted by a particle system will be made real, and there's no way to change this behavior.

To quote 3.4 manual on [Make Instances Real](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/apply.html#bpy-ops-object-duplicates-make-real)

> Make Instances Real creates a new object for each instance generated
> by the selected ones, and removes any direct instancing from those.
>
> In the end, each instance becomes a real object.
>
> ......
>
> Note
>
> Preserving relationships in recursive instancing cases (instancers
> instancing other instancer objects, etc.) is only supported to some
> extent currently.
>
> Simple cases (like an empty instancing a collection containing
> instances of some other collections) will usually work, but more
> complex cases will fail to fully reproduce the whole instancing
> hierarchy.

This means that if you're for example working on an architectural project `MyProject` without using BlenderBIM, and want to create a project north using instanced collections `MyProject_TrueNorth`, and decided to make a quick local adjustment before rendering, you can't just use another instanced collection `MyProject_TrueNorth_Adjusted` and make it real. You must instead copy the collection `MyProject` as a whole (either through the Duplicate Collection operator or ctrl+c-v), Select Objects, make the same changes to rotation or scale as present in `MyProject_TrueNorth`, and THEN make your local adjustments.